# Regex to allow only Numbers, alphabets, spaces and hyphens - Java

Tags: java, regex

Need to allow user to enter only Numbers or alphabets or spaces or hyphens OR combination of any of the above.

and i tried the following

```
String regex = "/^[0-9A-Za-z\s\-]+$/";
sampleString.matches(regex);
```

but it is not working properly. would somebody help me to fix please.

Comment: Java doesn't use `/regex/flags` syntax. Remove ``/``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue : your regex is trying to match `/` symbol at the beginning and at the end

In java there is no need of `/` before and after regex so use, `java!=javascript`

```
"^[0-9A-Za-z\\s-]+$"
```

`^[0-9A-Za-z\\s-]+$` : `^` beginning of match

`[0-9A-Za-z\\s-]+` : one or more alphabets, numbers , spaces and `-`

`$` : end of match

Comment: Thanks for the answer and btw i did not down vote your answer :) and i never do that too.

Comment: @SAR i am glad that i could help , me would never do that either :)

Comment: side -note :  note the time-frame between the answer and comment

Comment: sorry for replying late i tried to see if the value does not match like the following if(!enteredValue.matches(regEx)){sysout("does not match")} but if i give values like "hi 12112017 how_are_u" then i get the message "does not match". could you please help?. Thanks

Comment: @SAR simply because there is no `_` allowed by our regex so use this `^[0-9A-Za-z\\s-_]+$` and you will be good to go

Comment: thank you so much. it is all fixed now and works as expected.

Comment: i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You are close but need to make two changes.
The first is to double-escape (i.e., use \\ instead of \). This is due to the weirdness of Java (see the section "Backslashes, escapes, and quoting" in [Javadoc for the Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html)). The second thing is to drop the explicit reference to the start and end of the string. That's going to be implied when using matches(). So the correct Java code is

```
String regex = "[0-9A-Za-z\\s\\-]+";
sampleString.matches(regex);
```

While that will work, you can also replace the "0-9" reference with \d and drop the escaping of the "-". That gives you

```
String regex = "[\\dA-Za-z\\s-]+";
```

Comment: not a downvoter but there is no need to escape `-` , try it , but if you got downvoted because downvoter thinks it's a typo then excuse me for saying it's regex made of symbol , many posts will only be typos then

Comment: You are correct. I was typing fast and basing my answer on the original poster's regex. My bad :) For that matter, if cleaning up then the 0-9 can be replaced by \\d.

Comment: It would be nice if whoever is downgrading gives a reason. If there is a problem it would be more helpful if everybody knew what it is.

Comment: @LJinNJ and Pavneet_Singh Yes i agree with you both, taking time and helping others is not a joke and mistakes can be corrected if it is there and down voters must think of giving reason so that it would help others to give more information else it would discourage them.@LJinNJ, I am just making it positive by up voting and hopefully the person who down voted gives the correct reason to correct.